# How to add rows to a dataframe based on the diff of two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am struggling with this one.

Let's assume a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':['string1', 'string2'],
                   'col1':['some string','another string'],
                   'start':[100,1],
                   'end':[107,5]})

      col0            col1  start  end
0  string1     some string    100  107
1  string2  another string      1    5
```

The goal is the find the difference between `start` and `end` and then add that many rows to my dataframe, `ffill` the rest of the columns, and add a cumulative count for the range between `start` and `end`. Expected output below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col0':['string1']*8, 
                    'col1':['some string']*8,
                    'new_col':[x for x in range(100,108)]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col0':['string2']*5, 
                    'col1':['another string']*5,
                    'new_col':[x for x in range(1,6)]})

output = pd.concat([df2,df3]).reset_index(drop=True)

       col0            col1  new_col
0   string1     some string      100
1   string1     some string      101
2   string1     some string      102
3   string1     some string      103
4   string1     some string      104
5   string1     some string      105
6   string1     some string      106
7   string1     some string      107
8   string2  another string        1
9   string2  another string        2
10  string2  another string        3
11  string2  another string        4
12  string2  another string        5
```

My first though was to create a new dataframe...something like:

```
vals = list(zip(df['start'], df['end']+1))
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([i], columns=['new_col']) for val in vals for i in range(*val)])
```

but this seems rather inefficient and I am struggling to add the remaining data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st Create the list column using for loop with `range`, then the problem become [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
df['New']=[list(range(y,x+1)) for x , y in zip(df.pop('end'),df.pop('start'))]
unnesting(df,['New'])
   New     col0            col1
0  100  string1     some string
0  101  string1     some string
0  102  string1     some string
0  103  string1     some string
0  104  string1     some string
0  105  string1     some string
0  106  string1     some string
0  107  string1     some string
1    1  string2  another string
1    2  string2  another string
1    3  string2  another string
1    4  string2  another string
1    5  string2  another string
```

---

FYI

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```

Comment: @Chris yw :-)  -